# Calculate the sum of an Int Set

Tags: smt, cvc4

Using the set theory of CVC4 (version 1.8-prerelease [git master a90b9e2b]) I have defined a set of integers with a fixed cardinality

```
(set-logic ALL_SUPPORTED)
(set-option :produce-models true)

(declare-fun A () (Set Int))
(assert (= 5 (card A)))

;;(assert (= sum (???)))

(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

CVC4 then gives me one correct model

```
sat
(model
(define-fun A () (Set Int) (union (union (union (union (singleton 0) (singleton 1)) (singleton (- 1))) (singleton 2)) (singleton (- 2))))
)
```

Is there a way to ask for the sum of the integers in set A?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Patrick mentioned, these sorts of operations over arbitrary sets (like summing them up) is just not possible in SMTLib. However, you've more information: You know that the cardinality of the set is 5, so you can encode the summation indirectly.

The trick is to construct a set of the required cardinality explicitly and sum those elements. Obviously this only works well if the set is small enough, but you can "generate" the code automatically from a high-level API if necessary. (Hand coding it would be difficult!)

The below works with z3; Unfortunately CVC4 and Z3 differ in the function names for `Sets` a bit:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)

; declare-original set
(declare-fun A () (Set Int))
(assert (= 5 (card A)))

; declare the "elements". We know there are 5 in this case. Declare one for each.
(declare-fun elt1 () Int)
(declare-fun elt2 () Int)
(declare-fun elt3 () Int)
(declare-fun elt4 () Int)
(declare-fun elt5 () Int)

; form the set out of these elements:
(define-fun B () (Set Int) (store (store (store (store (store ((as const (Array Int Bool)) false) elt1 true)
                                                       elt2 true)
                                                elt3 true)
                                         elt4 true)
                                  elt5 true))

; make sure our set is equal to the set just constructed:
(assert (= A B))

; now sum-up the elements
(declare-fun sum () Int)
(assert (= sum (+ elt1 elt2 elt3 elt4 elt5)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (elt1 elt2 elt3 elt4 elt5 sum A))
```

This produces:

```
$ z3 a.smt2
sat
((elt1 0)
 (elt2 1)
 (elt3 3)
 (elt4 6)
 (elt5 7)
 (sum 17)
 (A (let ((a!1 (store (store (store ((as const (Set Int)) false) 0 true) 1 true)
                  3
                  true)))
  (store (store a!1 6 true) 7 true))))
```

For CVC4, the encoding is similar:

```
(set-option :produce-models true)
(set-logic ALL_SUPPORTED)

; declare-original set
(declare-fun A () (Set Int))
(assert (= 5 (card A)))

; declare the "elements". We know there are 5 in this case. Declare one for each.
(declare-fun elt1 () Int)
(declare-fun elt2 () Int)
(declare-fun elt3 () Int)
(declare-fun elt4 () Int)
(declare-fun elt5 () Int)

; form the set out of these elements:
(define-fun B () (Set Int) (union (singleton elt1)
                                  (union (singleton elt2)
                                         (union (singleton elt3)
                                                (union (singleton elt4) (singleton elt5))))))

; make sure our set is equal to the set just constructed:
(assert (= A B))

; now sum-up the elements
(declare-fun sum () Int)
(assert (= sum (+ elt1 elt2 elt3 elt4 elt5)))

(check-sat)
(get-value (elt1 elt2 elt3 elt4 elt5 sum A))
```

For which, cvc4 produces:

```
sat
((elt1 (- 4)) (elt2 (- 3)) (elt3 (- 2)) (elt4 (- 1)) (elt5 0) (sum (- 10)) (A (union (union (union (union (singleton 0) (singleton (- 1))) (singleton (- 2))) (singleton (- 3))) (singleton (- 4)))))
```

If the cardinality isn't fixed; I don't think you can code this up unless the domain is finite (or drawn from a finite subset of an infinite domain) as Patrick described.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you know all the elements that may possibly be contained in the set `A` (a.k.a. a **finite** super-set domain of `A`), one option is

```
(declare-fun A () (Set Int))
...
(declare-fun sum () Int)
(assert (= sum
           (+
               (ite (member 1 A) 1 0)
               (ite (member 2 A) 2 0)
               ...
               (ite (member k A) k 0)
           )
))
```

This may not be very efficient.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, but I am looking for a solution without knowledge about the contents of the set.

Comment: @JohnSmith *AFAIK*, it doesn't exist: look [here](http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/wiki/Sets) for the complete syntax of Sets. However, [CVC4](http://cvc4.cs.stanford.edu/wiki/About_CVC4) is [open-source](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/master/COPYING), so you may be able to fork it and implement this feature yourself, or to simply add a feature request on their [github](https://github.com/CVC4/CVC4/blob/1.4/examples/api/sets.cpp).

Comment: @PatrickTrentin Since the cardinality is known, one can explicitly construct the set. See my answer for details.